# Can C/C++ build all dynamic libraries into one bin file?

Tags: c++, c, go, dynamic, libc

When I develop across different OS's I find that a program built on one Linux system can not be run on another system, due to the different libc version.

How can I build in all the shared libraries just like golang did in c/c++?

Including libc and libcxx

Comment: I just want to link the static libc etc

Comment: cc -static etc usually works for me. man cc for more details about the -static switch.

Comment: You can't do that since different platforms have different architectures and also remember C is only source portable and not platform independent like java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run on multiple Linux systems, all you really need is to build using the oldest glibc from any of them.  The easiest way is to simply download a virtual machine image from an old system like CentOS 5 and build there.  You don't need to worry about static linking, just building against an old version will mean you are mostly compatible with newer versions.